# How to find most similar terms/words of a document in doc2vec?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I have applied Doc2vec to convert documents into vectors.After that, I used the vectors in clustering and figured out the 5 nearest/most similar document to the centroid of each cluster. Now I need to find the most dominant or important terms of these documents so that I can figure out the characteristics of each cluster. 
My question is is there any way to figure out the most dominat or simlar terms/word of a document in Doc2vec . I am using python's gensim package for the Doc2vec implementaton

Comment: Please provide sample text of your document as well as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out the most dominant words of your clusters, you can use any of these two classic approaches. I personally found the second one very efficient and effective for this purpose.

- Latent Drichlet Allocation (LDA): A topic modelling algorithm that will give you a set of topic given a collection of documents. You can treat the set of similar documents in the clusters as one document and apply LDA to generate the topics and see topic distributions across documents.
- TF-IDF: TF-IDF calculate the importance of a word to a document given a collection of documents. Therefore, to find the most important keywords/ngrams, you can calculate TF-IDF for every word that appears in the documents. The words with the highest TF-IDF then are you keywords. So:

  - calculate IDF for every single word that appears in the documents based on the number of documents that contain that keyword
  - concatenate the text of the similar documents (I 'd call it a super-document) and then calculate TF for each word that appears in this super-document
  - calculate TF*IDF for every word... and then TA DAAA... you have your keywords associated with each cluster.

  Take a look at Section 5.1 here for more details on the use of [TF-IDF](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9f3f/6f65344da1bd61f1311ab134c1a7bfcd0741.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

@TrnKh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46059380/130288) is good, but there is an additional option made available when using `Doc2Vec`.

Some gensim Doc2Vec training modes – either the default PV-DM (`dm=1`) or PV-DBOW with added word-training (`dm=0, dbow_words=1`) train both doc-vectors and word-vectors into the same coordinate space, and to some extent that means doc-vectors are near related word-vectors, and vice-versa.

So you could take an individual document's vector, or the average/centroid vectors you've synthesized, and feed it to the model to find `most_similar()` words. (To be clear that this is a raw vector, rather than a list of vector-keys, you should use the form of `most_similar()` that specifies an explicit list of `positive` examples.)

For example:

```
docvec = d2v_model.docvecs['doc77145']  # assuming such a doc-tag exists
similar_words = d2v_model.most_similar(positive=[docvec])
print(similar_words)
```